# Ruckus SmartZone API

Tags: api

I am having issues when trying to create a Zone using the API.

I can create the zone with the basic info, but as soon as I want to add another property (specifically "location") I get an error.

This is my dataset I use for the POST

```
def id_prov ={
"domainId": "$DomainId",
"name": "$ZoneName",
    "login": {
    "apLoginName": "xxxxx",
    "apLoginPassword": "xxxxx"
  },
"description": "$jira_summ",
    "version": "3.5.1.0.1010",
    "countryCode": "ZA"
"location": "$CalledStationName_val",
}
```

The API creates everything until I either include the "location" property in the original POST or if I try a PUT or PATCH atferwards.

Result value:

```
{"message":["object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: [\"location\"]"],"errorCode":101,"errorType":"Bad HTTP request"}
```

Anyone come across this or have any ideas on how to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A comma is required after "countryCode": "ZA". The post payload should look like this:

```
def id_prov ={
"domainId": "$DomainId",
"name": "$ZoneName",
    "login": {
    "apLoginName": "xxxxx",
    "apLoginPassword": "xxxxx"
  },
"description": "$jira_summ",
    "version": "3.5.1.0.1010",
    "countryCode": "ZA",
    "location": "$CalledStationName_val",
}
```

Comment: If this is the answer, it's a typo and the question should be closed as such.